# how to draw all line in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, osx-lion

i have a class `NSApplicationDelegate` where i will populate the `NSMutableArray *coordinate` with a lot of coordinate x,y.

how i can tell to the `NSView`class to draw all inside the array?
how i can pass the array to NSView class?

thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the coordinates are stored in the array, but you'll probably want to create an `NSBezierPath`:

```
// Maybe make bezPath an instance variable of your view?
NSBezierPath *bezPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

[bezPath setLineWidth:1.0];
// set up other parameters here

[bezPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(firstX, firstY)];

// loop over your source coordinates
for (i = 0; i < ... etc ...)
{
    [bezPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(source[i].x, source[i].y)];
}
```

In your NSView's subclass's `drawRect:` method, you could have something like:

```
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect) dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    [bezPath stroke];
}
```

Large chunks of this code is missing because you haven't given enough information, but you should have a gander at the [Cocoa Drawing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290) which will probably guide you in the right direction.

Comment: thank you for code.. but my problem is: how to pass the array?